# PHP algorithm to hash passwords

Tags: php, hash, passwords

I'm studying password encryption algorythms. I know the existence of bcrypt, scrypt, and varients, but I want to chanllenge myself on this question and that's why I came up with this algorythm in PHP:

```
$secret = md5( uniqid( mt_rand(), true ) ); // Length is 32
$passwd = 'qwert123';
$hash = $secret . hash( 'sha256', $secret + $passwd );
```

Since secret is randomly determined and added at the front of the password hash, I could verify the password input like this:

```
$secret = substr( $hash_from_db, 0, 32 );
$hash_from_db === $secret . hash( 'sha256', $secret + $input_from_user );
```

What do you think about this implementation? I would do like to receive some feedback about it. Thank you.

Comment: You have just reinvented [salting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salting_(cryptography)).

Comment: great work if you came up with that with out knowing what a salt was.

Comment: Use PHPass, it's smooth and guaranteed to work. The best protection out there at the moment.

Comment: Yes, that's how people were storing passwords *before* bcrypt and scrypt. If you are familiar with those, **use them**. They are several orders of magnitude better for password hashing. Also hashing != encryption.

Comment: Related question in sec.se: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/18197/20774

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using PHP 5 > 5.5, you can use the new [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.

There are compatibility functions for older versions of PHP - here's one: https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php

Answer (score 0):

MD5 is considered cryptographically broken - don't use it for security.

You're only hashing salt+password once. It took me about 10 seconds to find a tool that will crack a salted hash like this using a dictionary look up. Your implementation should not be considered secure against any form of determined attack.

To improve things consider hashing multiple times; using more than one salt; changing hash algorithm part-way through; introducing something unpredictable. Speed is not your friend - the more time you spend obfuscating things, the more secure it will be.

Comment: There's a tool that can find a SHA-256 collision when concatenated with 128 bits of entropy in a sane amount of time?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - A salt does _not_ add any entrophy, it will usually be stored plaintext after all, so it is known. Brute-forcing a single password is not more difficult if a salt was used, but you have to brute-force every password separately, that's the purpose of a salt.

Comment: @martinstoeckli: Yeah, I realise now that I misread the answer; the salt makes no difference to the cost of a dictionary attack (I was thinking of rainbow tables...)